# Async CSV parser with CancellationToken

Tags: c#, csv, asynchronous, streamreader, cancellationtokensource

I have the following code to parse UTF-8 encoded CSV files asynchronous.

```
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(filename, Encoding.UTF8, true))
        {
            bool canBreak = false;
            token.Register(() => canBreak = true);

            string rowasis = await reader.ReadLineAsync();

            while ((rowasis = await reader.ReadLineAsync()) != null)
            {
                if (canBreak == true)
                {
                    token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                }

                string[] row = rowasis.Split(';');

                Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}", row));
            }
        }
```

But I am unsure if this is enough to strop reading the file or do I have to rewrite the code. Thank you in advance for help.

Comment: Well what do your tests show? It's not clear why you have the `canBreak` part... why not just call `token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()` on every iteration of the loop? You should pass it into `ReadLineAsync ` as well, mind you...

Comment: Sadly `ReadLineAsync` does not accept any parameters. And if you would call `token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()` on every iteration I could not read the whole CSV file from start to end. `token.Register(() => canBreak = true);` is there because when I hit the `Cancel` button `cancellationToken.Cancel(true);
` is called which will fire the registered event and set `canBreak` to `true`. Please correct me if I am wrong, I am willing to learn.

Comment: "And if you would call token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested() on every iteration I could not read the whole CSV file from start to end" - why not? What happens? It should be absolutely fine... if it's cancelled, the exception will be thrown, otherwise, it shouldn't do anything. (But it's certainly a shame that ReadLineAsync doesn't accept a token.)

Comment: I've just tried it as you suggested, that `token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()` is present on every iteration. It does work! Thank you! You are amazing, I wouldnt even thinking on this. Actualy I've also used it this was `if (token.IsCancellationRequested == true) { token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested(); }`. Now I can simplify my source code.